# With select2 plunging how Enter key act like the Tab key to go next element and Enter+Shift key to go backward element

Tags: jquery-select2

I am struggling with some issues. Hope lot of bosses are waiting here in stack**overflow** to help me out from these issues.

**Requirement** : I want Enter key act like the Tab key to go next element and Enter+Shift key to go backward element in entire a project of form.

It is working like a charming hero the way i wrote code. But when i use Select2 plunging multiple time in a form defining it by common css class it is not working like the way i need.

**Problems**: It is not focusing and closing when enter key press and not go to next element when an item is selected.

I was seeing lot's of similar references here i have got but not work out.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
          //slect2 initialize here
            $(document).ready(function() {   
                $(".chosenCommon").select2({ width: '100%' });  
            });
            
            // Catch the keydown for the entire document
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            
              // Set self as the current item in focus
              var self = $(':focus'),
                // Set the form by the current item in focus
                form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
                focusable//,
               // next
                ;
            
              // Array of Indexable/Tab-able items   
              focusable = form.find('input:not([type="submit"],[type="reset"]),select,button,textarea,div[contenteditable=true]').filter(':visible:not([hidden],[readonly],[disabled], #save_btn, #update_btn, #delete_btn, #reset_btn):enabled');
            
              //next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(self)+1);  
              //alert(focusable.length);
            
              function enterKey()
              {
                if (e.which === 13 && !self.is('textarea')) 
                { 
                  // [Enter] key
            
                    // If not a regular hyperlink/button/textarea
                    if ( $.inArray(self, focusable) && (!self.is('a,button')) )
                    {
                        // Then prevent the default [Enter] key behaviour from submitting the form
                        e.preventDefault();
                    } // Otherwise follow the link/button as by design, or put new line in textarea
            
                    // Focus on the next item (either previous or next depending on shift)
                    var total = focusable.length;//alert(total);
                  var index = focusable.index(self);
            
                  if(e.shiftKey)
                  {
                    if(index > 0)
                    {
                      focusable.eq(index-1).focus();
                    }else{
                      focusable.eq(index).focus();
                    }
                  }else{
                    if(index < total)
                    {
                      focusable.eq(index+1).focus();
                    }else{
                      focusable.eq(index+total).focus();
                    }
            
                    // problem: slect an i tem from dropdown by pressing enter key it is not go to nex element
                    // alert(index);// -1
            
                    if(index==-1)
                    {
                      // what to do 
                    }
            
                  }
            
                  //focusable.eq( index + (e.shiftKey ? (index > 0 ? -1 :  0 ) : (index < total ? +1 : total ) ) ).focus();
            
                  //console.log(focusable);
                  
                  if( (total-1) == index)
                  {
                    //$("#save_btn").click();
                    //form.submit();
                  }   
            
                    return false;
                }
              }
            
              // We need to capture the [Shift] key and check the [Enter] key either way.
              if (e.shiftKey) { enterKey() } else { enterKey() }
            });
            </script>
```

```html
            
            <form action="#">
         
         First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
         Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
        
            <select class="chosenCommon" name="fruits">
                <option value="1">Banana</option>           
                <option value="2">Orange</option>
                <option value="3">Mango</option>
                
            </select>
        
            Full name: <input type="text" name="FullName" id="FullName" value="Mickey Mouse"><br>
        
            <input type="text" name="" id="address">
        
            <select class="chosenCommon" name="cities">
                <option value="1">Dhaka</option>           
                <option value="2">Chittagon</option>
                <option value="3">Rajshahi</option>
                <option value="3">Khulna</option>
            </select>
        
         <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_btn">
        </form>
```

Comment: You need to `customized` the `select2` plugin based on the requirement.

Comment: In `select2 ` on `enter` keypress current elemet will be select

Comment: Please be more specific with suggestion @jishan siddique

Comment: I can't generate your problem. It's working form quite well. can you be  more specific?

Comment: When i select an item from selection drop down list by pressing enter key it goes back to first index of form not next field. please help

Comment: I am waiting bosses, Is there anybody who can help me ):

Comment: There is a problem with select2 setting the tabindex to -1 so you will have to work around that by setting a variable outside the function to keep track of the current index and set next and previous index based on the count of enters or shift enters etc. I would recommend just not using select2. You could achieve the same thing using a little jquery and css. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Please boss don't make me hopeless instead of giving a proper solution. I am trying level my best to sort out this problem using jquery select2. I am not looking other way of around. If using outside of function help me sort out of this problem that would be also nice to me. But i could not able to write a proper function till now. Hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

`e.keyCode` and `e.which` are deprecated. You should use `e.key === "Enter"`. [see here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uvgmt9qs/1/)**

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      var self = $(this),
        form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
        focusable, next;
      focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
      next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) - 1);
      if (next.length) {
        next.focus();
      } else {
        form.submit();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    var self = $(this),
      form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
      focusable, next;
    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1);
    if (next.length) {
      next.focus();
    } else {
      form.submit();
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

**Updated Answer**

This will capture the enter key event in `select2`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#example').select2("close");
    var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible');
    inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L9hqje6v/)**

Comment: First of all I would love to give you lot's of thanks for giving effort on this issue. But I have to tell you with sorrow that I am still struggling with it. You have used select2 enable multiple option. Would you please try this issue to solve by not using multiple option and integrate select2 plugging with 2 select drop-down in a form just one after another. First enter key press it should be focus and second press enter select2 should be open after choose an item it should be close it and focus next element of the form. Hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: Vignesh Kumar Da i am waiting for your positive reply. Please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: @DidarulAlam Is issue solved? If not can you make me fiddle link for me?

Comment: Please help me bro, I will wait for your positive responds

Comment: Bro i know it's a challenging issue. But hopefully you could solve it

Comment: What is your issue now? can you explain

Comment: when select an item from a drown list by enter key pressing it is not close properly and it is not going next field of the form . you can check fiddle link. select dropdowns should be focus and open when first enter key pressing and then after choose an item from drop down list it should be close and cursor should go to next field of the form. thanks for your reply

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rodduralam/tzbu6fch/31/ 
please check the fiddle link

Comment: @DidarulAlam let me check and re post my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your humble co-operating. I am stuck with that issue for a long days and i don't want to loose select2 plugin facility also Enter key pressing go next field like tab key.

Comment: Vignesh Kumar da, hope you are doing good. What about issue status?  Thanks

Comment: waiting waiting Vignesh Kumar da. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Actually we should do the workaround to fix this since this is not regular one.

Comment: Yes, true, please try your best. I have visited your profile. you are too good. You are a very good problem solver. I am also trying...

Comment: @DidarulAlam check this tool https://joelpurra.com/projects/plusastab/

Comment: or you can remove the enter key event from select2 plugin and use it https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js

Comment: Let me try and see whether it meet my requirement or not. Thanks a lot